# What is the difference of a query with .exec and without?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I declare the next query:

```
      const User = await User.findOne().and([{
        "accounts.email": re.body.email
      },{
        status: 1
      }])
```

What is the difference if add `.exec()` at the end of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the functionality is concerned adding `.exec()` to `async/await` query wouldn't make a difference.

But as per mongoose documentation, you "should" use `.exec()` as it will provide you with better stack trace.

Check - [Should You Use exec() With await?](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await)

> Without `exec()`, the stack trace does **not** include the calling code.

> With `exec()`, the stack trace includes where in your code you called `exec()`